# How can I secure my Ubuntu 13.04 to prevent network attacks?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, security, events

Is there a way I could protect my pc computer from being hacked in an event where the internet conection will be opened?

Thing is I am going to Campus Party Colombia 2013 and I was sugested to format my computer before going and after the event, Is that really necesary?

I know Unix like systems got a higher level of securty than Windows, however as in campus party there will be people who know a lot about hacking and networking, I'd rather take some considerations.

Is there a way to protect my computer? If not, What about installing another GNU/linux flavor alongside my Ubuntu installation?

I'd apreciate any advice on this.

Comment: If I have physical access to your machine you can consider the machine compromised. Since you tell us that this is a hacker oriented crowd, I'd take the advice. If you were going to a Petty Theft Convention 2013 it would probably be a bad idea to leave your backpack unattended on the floor for much the same reason.

Comment: @msw, others - shouldn't this be migrated to IT Security instead of closed?

Comment: Given that I have high regard for @slm and yet we've come to diametrically opposite conclusions would seem to support the bit that answers are "almost entirely based on opinions".

Comment: @msw Is there a way in which I could improve this question? I do really need to know an answer to what I am asking, but have not found the words so that it can fit the site's rules. I'd apreciate sugestions

Comment: @Francisco I understand your concern, but I don't know that the question can be framed in a way that doesn't resort to opinion. If I were to ask you "I am going on holiday in London, should I bring an umbrella?" no quantity of facts will provide a definite answer. Since we're now getting into philosophical confirmation theory I'll leave you my practical advice: if you are concerned that your machine will be hacked, assume that it will be and reload it upon your return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu is fully up to the task. You just need to take some time to lock it down. Here is a high level list of some areas that you should spend time both familiarizing yourself and also tending to:

1. I would highly suggest that you make sure the firewall is configured and running.
2. Also I would make sure that any unused services such as a web server (Apache) are shutdown prior to going to the even.
3. Make sure that the system is as up to date as possible (`apt-get update` followed by `apt-get dist-upgrade`).

This tutorial should help you with getting the basics done in short order, titled: [How to secure an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server - Part 1 The Basics](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics).

If you want to go beyond the basics there is a more detailed list, titled: [Security - Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Security), which covers more indepth ways of securing your system and the different software that can help with the task.

Beyond those things I don't see any reason to be overly concerned with taking it to this event.